# How to download an archive or directory from Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: files-and-directories, wolfram-cloud

I don't own Mathematica, but have a (free) Wolfram Cloud account. I'd like to download all of the files in a given Wolfram Cloud directory to my computer. I've used `CloudExport` to create downloadable gifs and the like, and I can download files individually by clicking the Download link in the cloud directory, but have not figured out how to download in bulk.

To archive and download, e.g. the directory `"Files"` I've tried things like

```
archive=CreateArchive["Files"]
CloudExport[archive, "zip", "Zips/testarchive.zip"]
(* CloudExport doesn't support "zip" *)
```

and

```
archive=CreateArchive["Files"]
CloudObject[archive]
(* creates a URL, but one that results in a 404 browser error *)
```

and other variants, but they all fail to do the job at some point.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Export["asd1.txt", 1];
Export["asd2.txt", 1];
arch=CreateArchive[Directory[], (DeleteFile[#];#)&@CreateFile[]];
CopyFile[arch, Append[CloudObject["test.zip"], Permissions->"Public"]]
```

Replace `Directory[]` with your actual directory of interest, of course, and `"test.zip"` with your target directory.

Comment: Yasss! `CopyFile` to a `CloudObject` works, but I think it could be simplified to just something like `CopyFile[CreateArchive["Files"],CloudObject["test.zip"]]`, where `"Files"` is the name of the directory to be archived.

Comment: @brainjam if that works let me know. You'll definitely want the `Permissions-><some permission set that is easy for you to access>` though.

Comment: The only thing I want to do is download the archive, which I can do from within Wolfram Cloud just by clicking on the newly created `CloudObject` or using the `Download` option in the directory view.  So no permissions required.

Comment: You can also just click on the URL that comes in the output though and it downloads automatically

Comment: Turns out that the value of my `$Permissions` is `Public`, which maybe explains why I get away without setting `Permissions`.